Finding niche image files relating to medical imaging
I have a very specific image formatting request and thought someone here may be able to help me.
I'm looking for a list of image formats that are used in medical imaging. I've had trouble finding files in this format and or generating them using online tools, so if anyone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.
Here is the list of the formats:

JPEG-LS Lossy (Near-Lossless)
JPEG 2000 Part 2 Multi-component (Lossless Only)
JPEG 2000 Part 2 Multi-component
High-Throughput JPEG 2000 (Lossless Only)
High-Throughput JPEG 2000 with RPCL Options (Lossless Only)
High-Throughput JPEG 2000 Image Compression

Thanks so much!

So at the end you search images in this format?

Hi and welcome to Photo.SE! Could you perhaps elaborate on why you need this list? I ask because there might be a different way to achieve your end goal then listing formats.

Hi - thanks ! Yeah the purpose of having these files is to create DICOM files (which are medical imaging files) that include these image file formats. I'm using it to test my program to see that it works with all file types.

JPEG 2000 was never widely adopted in typical photography applications (cameras/etc); it seems the HEIF codec gained favor first; and it still has not replaced the venerable jpeg standard entirely (or even close).
There are numerous programs that can read/write JPEG 2000; I'm sure some can convert/export to the format as well. And there are numerous online converters that will convert a .jpg to a .jp2; but they seem to be largely limited in options (e.g. lossy/lossless). You can actually just rename a .jpg to .jp2 and it will work fine; but that would be rather pointless I think.

IrfanView is pretty good at spotting valid images with an incorrect or even missing extension. I just renamed a .JPG file to .JP2 and tried to open it with IrfanView, and it warned me that I was opening a JPG file with incorrect extension. Just for interest.

Yeah - the tools I've found online have been very limited ... specifically in finding some of the "parts" as written on that wikipedia page. ex) JPEG2000 Part 15.
I think I may need to dive into some more dense academic type papers to understand how it works since I don't think I'll have much luck finding it. Thanks for your help and contextual knowledge!!
